# getElementById doesn't work only one element but works for others

Tags: javascript, html

One getElementById does not work although the others do, everything is spelled correctly and the syntax is correct. testTitle does not return anything in the console although the others do, I have tried rearranging the lines however it results in the same thing.

```
      <!--test name-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 offset-s3">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="testTitle" required />
            <label for="testTitle">test name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--subject-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 offset-s3">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="testSubject" required />
            <label for="testSubject">subject</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--test date-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 offset-s3">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" class = "datepicker" id="testDate" required />
            <label for="testDate">test date</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
    add.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
      
      const testSubject = document.getElementById("testSubject").value;
      const testDate = document.getElementById("testDate").value;
      const testTitle = document.getElementById("testTitle").value;
      console.log(testTitle);
      console.log(testSubject);
      console.log(testDate);
    });
```

Comment: Provide a running example which exhibits this behaviour. There is nothing visibly wrong with the code you provided, as far as I can see.

Comment: Could you show us your full code so we can see what is wrong? It would help, try linking a sololearn page if possible.

Comment: The code looks great, try adding the `value` attribute across all the input.